# Python: How to create a function? e.g. f(x) = ax^2

Tags: python, function, lambda

I want to have some sort of reference to a function but I do not know if I need to use a `def f(x)` or a `lambda` of some kind.

For instance I'd like to `print f(3)` and have it output `9a`, or is this not how python works?

**Second question**: Assuming I have a working function, how do I return the `degree` of it?

Comment: First, please ask only one question per "question". Second, it's not clear what you're asking here… Are you asking how you would define a function? And, if so, what's wrong with http://www.google.ca/search?q=python+define+function ?

Comment: Agreed with @DavidWolever, though I think it's pretty clear that you're looking for symbolic math.

Comment: So if I have def f(x): return a*x**2, I can't have the "a" term as a free floating parameter?

Comment: Very unclear question... What does 9a stand for?

Comment: @gg.kaspersky passing in 3 as the argument to f(x) which is ax^2, thus a(3)^2 = a9 = 9a

Comment: Python is a programming language, not a symbolic expression evaluator. You might be looking for `maxima` or something else.

Comment: I got it, but this seems very exotic to python. Maybe you can do that in python, but in any case you will need to define the a parameter.

Comment: Alright so I am probably just misunderstanding what I can do with Python. I was assuming that Python had some kind of function support so that if I had def f(x) = ax^2, I could print f(3) and have it automatically return something in the form of 9a

Comment: @AgainstASicilian You are misunderstanding - you can use partial functions, but that's not what you're after - maybe have a look at sagemath.org - that's Python with mathematical steroids that does all sorts of stuff including BLAS

Comment: @AgainstASicilian, what languages can do that sort of thing?

Comment: @AgainstASicilian, the programming paradigms supported by python (procedural, object-oriented, functional) don't allow you to do what you are asking.

Comment: @gg.kaspersky I think that's a bit too strict of a statement. You can achieve the goal with OOP.

Comment: @LevLevitsky, you are right, I said so just because it seems to me very unnatural. You can achieve the goal by any programming paradigms, because they all are Turing-equivalent. Just some of them are more appropriate for specific tasks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To create a function, you define it. Functions can do anything, but their primary use pattern is taking parameters and returning values. You have to decide how exactly it transforms parameters into the return value.

For instance, if you want `f(x)` to return a number, then `a` should also be a numeric variable defined globally or inside the function:

```
In [1]: def f(x):
   ...:     a = 2.5
   ...:     return a * x**2
   ...: 

In [2]: f(3)
Out[2]: 22.5
```

Or maybe you want it to return a string like this:

```
In [3]: def f(x):
   ...:     return str(x**2) + 'a'
   ...: 

In [4]: f(3)
Out[4]: '9a'
```

You have to specify your needs if you need more help.

---

**EDIT:** As it turns out, you want to work with polynomials or algebraic functions as objects and do some algebraic stuff with them. Python will allow doing that, but not using standard data types. You can **define a class** for a polynomial and then define any methods or functions to get the highest power or anything else. But `Polynomial` is not a built-in data type. There may be some good libraries defining such classes, though.

Comment: So if I have f(x) return some arbitrary polynomial, I can't have a process that returns the degree (i.e. the highest power of the variable)? For instance, if def f(x) is a polynomial using variable x, I can't have some way to return the highest power of x?

Comment: @AgainstASicilian Edited answer in response to your question.

Answer (score 2):

Python (and most other computer languages) don't do algebra, which is what you'll need if you want *symbolic* output like this. But you could have a function `f(a,x)` which returns the result for particular (numerical) values of `a`:

```
def f(a, x):
   return a*x*x
```

But if you want a program or language which actually does algebra for you, check out [sympy](http://sympy.org/en/index.html) or commercial programs like Mathematica.

If you are just working with polynomials, and you just need a data structure which deals well with them, check out [numpy and its polynomial class](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.poly.html).

Answer (score 1):

I normally use lambda for short and simple functions:

```
f = lambda a, x: a * x**2
```

here a and x are parameters of my function. You need to enter a and x

```
f(2,4)
```

If you want a as a constant parameter eg. a=2:

```
f = lambda x: 2 * x**2
f(5)
```

if you have a list of input values of x, you can combine map with lambda.
it is straighforward and easily readable.

```
(*map(lambda x: 3 * x**2, [1,2,3,4]),)
```

or

```
list(map(lambda x: 3 * x**2, [1,2,3,4])
```

cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
def func():
    print "F(x) = 2x + 3"
    x = int(raw_input('Enter an integer value for x: '))
    Fx = 2 * x + 3
    return Fx

print func()
```

have fun :)

Answer (score 0):

Cheese,

you can use the `def` function in Python to create a math function, you could type this:

```
def f(x):
    return(2x + (3 + 3) * 11 + 88) # <- you could make your own function.

print(f(3))
```

Log:

```
220
```

Like **THAT**

or in this:

```
def f(a, x):
    return((a + x) ** (a * x))
```

then...

```
print(f(1, 2))
```

Log...

```
6
```