# Functions and "catching values"

Tags: python, function, parameters

I just wrote a program that converts random integers for miles and converts them to kilometers and prints them in a table with 2 columns. I have to write another program and I have no idea what it is asking for. This is the question I was asked, write a program that prints out the same table but by using a function that returns the kilometers for a miles parameter. Use a loop in main and generate random integers, but catch the value returned by the function and use it in the loop to print a line of the table. Use same table format as before. I am very new to python and get confused easily, any help would be appreciated!

Here is my code from the last program:

import random

```
def main() :

print('Miles\tKilometers')

for value in range(10):
       miles = random.randrange(10, 60)
       print(format(miles, '.2f'), find_kilometers(miles), sep='\t')
def find_kilometers(miles):
  kilometers = miles * 1.60934
  return format(kilometers, '.5f')

main()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: How to create a function? e.g. f(x) = ax^2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13544078/python-how-to-create-a-function-e-g-fx-ax2)

Comment: "catching the value" refers to doing something with what the function **returns**.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as though you already fulfilled the requirements of your program. `find_kilometers` returns an answer that you use to print your result. Maybe for part 1 you were expected to hard-code everything in one block of code.

"Capture" here means "saving a return value in a variable," but your program simply uses the return value immediately by passing it as an argument to print. You could have done:

```
for value in range(10):
       miles = random.randrange(10, 60)
       kilometers = find_kilometers(miles) 
       # ^-- kilometers stores the return value from find_kilometers()
       print(format(miles, '.2f'), kilometers, sep='\t')
```

but your version is correct and more to-the-point than the alternative. Regardless, if you need to follow the instructions strictly, I would save the return value and *then* use it in `print()` just in case.